# TypeScript generic type inference from function parameters

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to build a string render function that takes a an event type and type checks if the correct metaData is provided:

Consider this code:

```
enum EventType {
  NEW_APPLICATION = "NEW_APPLICATION",
  APPLICATION_CANCELLED = "APPLICATION_CANCELLED"
}

const renderers = {
  [EventType.APPLICATION_CANCELLED]: (metaData: { a: string }) => "bar",
  [EventType.NEW_APPLICATION]: (metaData: { b: string }) => "bar"
};

function render<T extends EventType>(eventType: T, metaData: Parameters<typeof renderers[T]>[0]) {
  return renderers[eventType](metaData); // <-- compile error
}

const rendered = render(EventType.APPLICATION_CANCELLED, { a: "foo" });
```

Type checking in calling the render function on the bottom works flawlessly but I get a compile error on the return statement inside the render function:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'Parameters<{ APPLICATION_CANCELLED: (metaData: { a: string; }) => string; NEW_APPLICATION: (metaData: { b: string; }) => string; }[T]>[0]' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ a: string; } & { b: string; }'.
  Type '{ a: string; } | { b: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ a: string; } & { b: string; }'. 
    Type '{ a: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ a: string; } & { b: string; }'.
       ...
```

It seems I get a an | between the metadata types one way and an & the other way. I cannot see why. Anybody got an idea?

Comment: Of course I could skip the render function completely and do something like: renderers[EventType.APPLICATION_CANCELLED]({a: "foo"}) but want the typing of the render function to work because it has to more than just in this example.

Comment: There's no great type-safe solution for dealing with the implementation of `render()`; you should probably just use an `any` type assertion like [this](https://tsplay.dev/RwRqEW) and move on.  The underlying issue is the same as the linked question and in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581)

Comment: Thanks, I'll go for the any option there as it still provides me type safety in the most important place, calling the render function itself.